# How much refraction occurs as a fraction of all reflection and refraction?

Tags: optics, reflection, refraction

[image]

When light reaches a boundary between materials below the critical angle, some of it refracts and some of it reflects. For example, glass acts as a partial mirror with a dark background.

Assuming no light is lost in the process, how much of total light in the incident ray is refracted as a function of $\theta_1$ (but of course $\theta_c ,n_1,n_2$ and other properties of the materials will probably matter too (whether the reflection was hard or soft, for instance)).

Intuitively, the amount refracted seems to be maximum when $\theta=0$, so perhaps $A\cos(\pi\frac{\theta}{\theta_c})$ is a viable function for the fraction refracted when $\theta > \theta_c$.

I hope there's an explanation that doesn't explain this away with a single experimental constant associated with each material (that is, is theoretically derived).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for the [Fresnel equations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fresnel_equations). (See, e.g., http://physics.gmu.edu/~ellswort/p263/feqn.pdf for a derivation.)